# Do we want the embedded videos feature enabled on Web Applications?

Tags: discussion

NOTICE: As of April 28, 2023, this post has more than 30 days as [featured](/questions/tagged/featured). The *bot* that remove old featured meta post from the **Community Bulletin** runs weekly so it's very likely that this post will automatically be removed this weekend.

I don't have plans about doing the "featured dance" to keep it on *Community Bulleting* but it will remain "open"  for feedback from the community until further notice. So far there is no deadline.

I think that there is still too much to add before making a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). Please be patient, it might take a while but once we get enough feedback in favor of enabling embedded videos it might happen.

---

A user from our community posted a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) in the early days of this community in Meta Stack Exchange, making reference to a question that he has posted here:
[Provide a way to embed videos in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66397/289691)

Here is a post with a list of the sites that have enabled this feature:

[Which sites have YouTube embedding on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297500/289691)

I'm wondering if this feature benefits our community. What do you think?

Comment: @V2Blast Thanks for the corrections.

Answer (score 2):

I like the idea of embedded videos, as long as they are hosted by Stack Exchange. Videos can often be very helpful to illustrate some points, and a real video player is much better than an animated GIF.

I'm nervous about videos hosted elsewhere, though, like YouTube. What if the person who owns the YouTube video deletes the video? Is the video part of the answer, and licensed under Creative Commons BY-SA, just like the answer is? Could another user take the video, edit it, and create their answer post with the edit? Or edit the current answer post with an edited video?

Comment: The referred feature request is about embedding YouTube videos. AFAIK at this time Stack Exchange doesn't host videos, that should be suggested as a new feature request in [meta.se]. Considering this, please clarify if under the current state do you agree that YouTube videos embedding be allowed or not. This clarity is important as this this might allow or not to convert change this question into a [meta-tag:feature-request].

Comment: @Rubén I'm nervous about YouTube embeds but I don't feel strongly about it. It's fine by me if YouTube embeds are enabled on this site.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

No.

I don't think the issues the site has would be helped with videos.

If the person asking the question never returns to vote or accept an answer, the presence of the video will not change that.

I think that most of the questions I am involved with can be adequately answered without even attaching a video. Let alone embedding one.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, embedded videos would be a great addition to our community. They can help users more clearly illustrate questions and answers, and provide more details and examples. They can enhance questions and answers and make them more informative by showing rather than telling.